# How to make missed calls?

Tags: android, phone-call

I am working on an Android app on which I want to be
able to make calls but with a very precise restriction, this is
"making missed calls". What I want is, to be able to hang up just the
moment the phone starts ringing.

right now I am able to know when the phone starts to try and make the
call, but for a few seconds there is no "ringing" activity over the
network, which is what I am willing to do.

How can I stop this exact moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `onCallStateChanged()` via the PhoneStateListener you can only detect when the phone starts to make an outgoing call and when the outgoing call is hunged up but you can't determine when a "ringing" is started. I tried once, check out the code below:

An outgoing call starts from `IDLE` to `OFFHOOK` when dialed out, to IDLE when hunged up.
The only workaround is to use a timer to hang up after the outgoing call starts and some few seconds passes, but then, you're never guaranteed the phone will start ringing.

> Here's the code:

```
  public abstract class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        static CallStartEndDetector listener;

  

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        savedContext = context;
        if(listener == null){
            listener = new CallStartEndDetector();
        }


            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        telephony.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

   

    public class CallStartEndDetector extends PhoneStateListener {
        int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        boolean isIncoming;

        public PhonecallStartEndDetector() {}


        //Incoming call-   IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when hung up
        //Outgoing call-  from IDLE to OFFHOOK when dialed out, to IDLE when hunged up

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            if(lastState == state){
                //No change
                return;
            }
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    isIncoming = true;
                     //incoming call started
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing down on them
                    if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                        isIncoming = false;
                       //outgoing call started
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    //End of call(Idle).  The type depends on the previous state(s)
                    if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                        // missed call
                    }
                    else if(isIncoming){
                          //incoming call ended
                    }
                    else{
                       //outgoing call ended                                              
                    }
                    break;
            }
            lastState = state;
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onCallStateChanged() in [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)