# Missed call detection in android

Tags: android

I want to develop a missed call detector .Which notify through broadcast reciver I found the code from the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408247/how-to-make-missed-calls)

```
public abstract class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        static CallStartEndDetector listener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        savedContext = context;
        if(listener == null){
            listener = new CallStartEndDetector();
        }


            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        telephony.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }



    public class CallStartEndDetector extends PhoneStateListener {
        int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        boolean isIncoming;

        public PhonecallStartEndDetector() {}


        //Incoming call-   IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when hung up
        //Outgoing call-  from IDLE to OFFHOOK when dialed out, to IDLE when hunged up

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            if(lastState == state){
                //No change
                return;
            }
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    isIncoming = true;
                     //incoming call started
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing down on them
                    if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                        isIncoming = false;
                       //outgoing call started
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    //End of call(Idle).  The type depends on the previous state(s)
                    if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                       //toast here for missed call
                    }
                    else if(isIncoming){
                          //incoming call ended
                    }
                    else{
                       //outgoing call ended                                              
                    }
                    break;
            }
            lastState = state;
        }

    }

}
```

The above code woking fine .But when i got the missed call from same no it repeat the missed call detection . How i will got the toast only once please help

Comment: This is the best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52232504/843001 it's different approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi everyone I have got the solution now its working fine with missed call.

Here my Class code `MyCallListener` extended by `BroadcastReciever`

```
private static boolean ring=false;
private static boolean callReceived=false;
private String callerPhoneNumber;
private Context saveContext;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent)
{
     saveContext=mContext;
   // Get the current Phone State


    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if(state==null){
      return;
    }

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    number= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    currentTimeStamp=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    // If phone state "Rininging"
    if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
    {           
              ring =true;
             // Get the Caller's Phone Number

      }



     // If incoming call is received
    if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
     {
            callReceived=true;
      }


     // If phone is Idle
    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
    {
              // If phone was ringing(ring=true) and not received(callReceived=false) , then it is a missed call
               if(ring==true&&callReceived==false)
               {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "missed call : "+number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       //workingWithFunctions();
                        ring=false;
               }
               callReceived=false;
  }}
```

dont forgot to define receiver  in manifest file

```
 <receiver android:name="com.abc.broadcastrecivers.MyBroadcastReciver" />
```

in the application tag

Comment: This will not work. If the user dismisses an incoming call, this code will detect it as a missed call. Also, if the user receives a missed call while he is on another call, this code will not detect it.

Comment: This is the best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52232504/843001 it's different approach

Answer (score 4):

```
     public class callServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
        {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {

                phoneStateListener phoneListener = new phoneStateListener(context);
                telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

            }`enter code here`

            public void onDestroy() {
                telephonyManager.listen(null, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
            }
        }





    public class phoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
        {

            private Context mContext;
            private static boolean ringing =false;
            private static boolean call_received =false;



            //Constructor
            public phoneStateListener(Context context)
            {
                    mContext = context;

            }


            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
            {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                try
                {


                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                            ringing = true;
                            // Get the Caller's Phone Number
                            break;
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                            call_received =true;
                            break;

                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                            // If phone was ringing(ringing=true) and not received(call_received=false) , then it is a missed call
                            if(ringing ==true&& call_received ==false)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "missed call : "+incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                ringing =false;
                            }
                            call_received =false;
                            break;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        }
```

> > ```
> >     <receiver android:name=".callServiceReceiver">
> >         <intent-filter>
> >             <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
> >         </intent-filter>
> > ```

```
   </receiver>
```

Comment: This is not working right when you have a second call in waiting and you do not hook off the second one, still talking to the first call (multiple SIMs, waiting call activated, conference call)