# Android : How can I avoid android os to kill my service

Tags: android, android-service

I am creating an app that keep tracks of missed-calls, the problem I am facing is my app is killed by android os and my service stops running so after that I am not getting missed call data in my app what shall I do ? are there any special permissions that I should include in my manifest to keep listening to the calls. or can I avoid android os from killing my service, or what else can I do to keep my service alive. I have used a started service, but still it is not helping. what shall I do ?

Comment: check this it will definately help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665183/broadcast-receiver-for-missed-call-in-android

Comment: Use firebaseJobDispatcher https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Comment: and this link too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185989/missed-call-detection-in-android

Comment: Make sure your service is STICKY. Can you post your service's "onStartCommand"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BroadcastReceiver` instead `Service` [Broadcast Receiver For New Incoming Phone Call"](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_Phone_Call_Broadcast_Receiver__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=61)