# How to detect unanswered outgoing call?

Tags: android

I used to monitor the call log to get 0 duration for the purpose. However the google team refused me the right to do so, saying this was not necessary.
Is there any other way to detect an unanswered outgoing call?

Comment: Code is irrelevant to the question - it worked flawless. Example: App listens for outgoing calls and selects only this with duration=0, then asks the user if he wants to redial the number. However recently android people have denied me the right to read call log, saying this was not necessary for the purpose, which is namely redialling the last unanswered phone number. So, if reading the call log is not necessary, therefore there must be another, known to Google, way to detect unanswered outgoing calls. I think this is not a secret for the rest of the humanity.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I did not pay attention that your question is *not* about [the incoming calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185989/missed-call-detection-in-android). I've removed the 'possible duplicate (...)' comment