# How to do something when i detect missed call but NOT WHEN CALL IS REJECTED

Tags: java, android, kotlin, call, incoming-call

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185989/missed-call-detection-in-android?tg_rhash=c3f1148562714f) article but I want to do something only when I receive a missed call. I see that the article works in missed and rejected call. If the state was rinning and the new is idle I know that of that way I can detect missed call but it's activate if the call is rejected. How can I detect ONLY MISSED CALL and IGNORE REJECTED CALL?

Comment: I am just exploring TelecomManager which have endCall() method can it possible to customize that class.

Comment: Can you explain better? What do you suggested?

Comment: Is there is any way to extend TelecomManager class and override endCall() method of that class for current incoming call.